# How to make an image within a flexbox within a grid take up 100% height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `grid`, within my `grid` I have a "cell" which is set to `display:flex;` What I would like to do is make it so that the image that's on the left side of this cell takes up 100% of the height of the container and have the width scale proportionally.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid>div img {
  /* image should be 100% height of cont */
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.cell-content {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" />
    <div class="cell-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Hac habitasse platea dictumst
        quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a. Facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Viverra
        tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not even sure the `grid` part of this layout matters in this case, but I recreated a minimized version of my grid just in case. Essentially I want the image to be touching the top and bottom of the border and have the width of the image scale proportionally. Right now there is a slight gap above and below the image.

Comment: you can start by removing `align-items:center` and `height:100%`. You will have what you want but the image will be distorted

Comment: I guess it's impossible, we will have a cycle doing the calculation. The browser cannot go back to calculate the width after setting the height

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58350222/8620333 .. almost the same issue and no real solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was afraid that was the case, thank you. I will just have to settle for a background image and a static width for the container.