# CSS grid renders behind parent's scroll bar in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an absolutely positioned panel (fixed height, `overflow scroll`) and a grid with square tiles (10 columns). In Chrome, the grid renders correctly:

[image]

But in FF/Safari, the last column is displayed behind wrapper's scrollbar which is odd:

[image]

[image]

What I want is the same behavior in all browsers (like in Chrome). How do I get this?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oleq/wybj3kvL/13/)

```css
:root {
 --ck-character-grid-tile-size: 24px;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper { 
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  background: blue;
}

button {
  background: yellow;
  width: var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size);
  height: var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size);
  min-width: var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size);
  min-height: var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size);
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button><button>x</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you can add padding-right on the parent or margin-right on the child to stay from the scrollbar area : https://jsfiddle.net/61mnjezw/

Comment: I get the same results in Chrome as I do in Firefox for your fiddle.

Comment: On my Chrome (78.0.3904.108) I get the incorrect result (the same as in Firefox and Safari). Maybe it's OS specific (how scrollbars behave)?

Comment: the snippet goes wrong for my latest Firefox under windows, fine with chrome

Comment: @TylerH Forgot to mention, I'm running things on MacOS. It could make a difference.

Comment: safari was the key word here about MacOs :) but my win FF goes wrong too.

Comment: OK, I took another look. The Fiddle in Chrome hides the grid behind the scrollbar when I first load the page, but then when I click "run" (without changing anything), it repaints with the grid expanded so that the scrollbar isn't covering it up. Very weird.

Comment: and padding/margin doesn't solve anything here ? this behavior is since ever , it is not only about a grid child . might be a few dupes that will be good enough

Comment: since this a known bug and can be solved in many other ways, in your case since you know how many items there will be you can define a width to the grid `width: calc(var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size) * 10);` maybe tweak it to account for borders

Comment: @TylerH yes this is common in Chrome where the repaint fixes some issue or to be more accurate trigger some extra calculation. You can do this with an animation for example and it will also work without the need of running the snippet again: https://jsfiddle.net/73tcpwky/ .. Some related question where I used that hack: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58350222/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/58289173/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CSS Tricks article, Preventing a Grid Blowout](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/), the issue is connected with the sizing of the grid:

> The real fix isn't all that difficult — we only need to understand what is happening. I can't promise I'm explaining this 100% accurately, but the way I understand it, **the minimum width of a grid column is auto**. […]
>
> To apply our fix, we need to make sure that there is the column has a **definite** minimum width instead of auto.

The fix proposed in article, `minmax`, seems to be working also for the case in question:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat( 10, minmax( 0, var(--ck-character-grid-tile-size) ) );
```

The simpler version, using `fr` unit, also seems to work:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat( 10, minmax( 0, 1fr ) );
```

Demo of the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/gp8r0f94/

Answer (score -3):

That's just how things are, but you can use JS to calculate the width of the scrollbar and add that as a padding. You can use this answer:

[Prevent scroll-bar from adding-up to the Width of page on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome)

I replaced margin with padding:

```
var checkScrollBars = function(){
    var b = $('body');
    var normalw = 0;
    var scrollw = 0;
    if(b.prop('scrollHeight')>b.height()){
        normalw = window.innerWidth;
        scrollw = normalw - b.width();
        $('#container').css({paddingRight:'-'+scrollw+'px'});
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think the question has already been answered, please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that only links to an existing answer elsewhere on the site.

Comment: It's a different question which happens to solvable with the same answer of another question. Maybe someone will offer a different solution and closing down the answer takes that opportunity away.

Comment: In that case, you should provide a gist of the answer here, as link-only answers are still of little value. What if the answer (or its question) you link to gets deleted? What if it gets changed? Etc.